# Rolling sum on 3 month

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

This is the data frame

```
Date        ID  Value
15/12/2016   1   200
15/10/2016   1   100
15/9/2016    1   55
15/04/2016   1   1000
15/12/2016   2   300
15/10/2016   2   200
15/9/2016    2   100
15/04/2016   2   1000
```

I'd like to repeat the rolling sum on 3 month for each ID. Note that in the example the IDs are just 2 but in my DB are n.

The output should be

```
Date        ID  Value  Rolling_Sum
15/12/2016   1   200   355
15/10/2016   1   100   155
15/9/2016    1   55    55
15/04/2016   1   1000  1000
15/12/2016   2   300   600
15/10/2016   2   200   300
15/9/2016    2   100   100
15/04/2016   2   1000  1000
```

Thanks

Comment: What happened to `1000` ? Please check input and expected output, not very clear. From To dates seems to be in wrong order?

Comment: I hope that this example works better.. this in just a simple example of what i need.. in 15/04/2016 you should sum value of last 3 month.. but you don't have Data.. one of my problem is that i don't have contineus data: for example from 15/09 to 15/04 are 5 month so the sum is just the value in 15/09 (55)

Comment: the `Value` column in your two chunks are different..

Comment: thanks.. I've fixed it

Comment: Also, if your window is 3 months, the first rolling sum should be 300 in your expected output, otherwise your window is 4 months.

Comment: i'd like something like 15/12 to 15/11, 15/11 to 15/10, 15/10 to 15/9. 3 month..

Comment: It's not clear how you want to group three months. The following (using `lubridate`) gives your desired output but somehow I doubt it's what you want:
`df %>% mutate(Date = dmy(Date), rounded_date = floor_date(Date, "4 months")) %>% group_by(ID, rounded_date) %>% mutate(Rolling_Sum = order_by(Date, cumsum(Value)))`